# AOP Logging not working java

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using AOP to perform logging for my servies call. Its a mven Spring MVC project.
Following are my configurations:

I have configured aspectj, aspectweaver and aspectjtools dependency in pom.xml

Following is my application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="thirdPartyLogging" class="com.test.ThirdPartyLoggingActivity">
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="logging" ref="thirdPartyLogging">
        <aop:pointcut id="servicesCall"
            expression="execution(* com.test.manager.SearchManager.getSearchData(..))"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="servicesCall" method="beforeRequest"/>
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="servicesCall" method="afterRequest" arg-names = joinPoint"/>
        <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="servicesCall" throwing="ex" method="serviceCallException" 
            arg-names = "joinPoint, ex"/>
   </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Following are my beforerequest, after request and serviceCallException methods:

```
public void beforeRequest(){
        loggingThreadLocal.get().setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("Inside before request");
    }

    public void afterRequest(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        loggingThreadLocal.get().setEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String invokingServiceName = joinPoint.getClass().toString();
        loggingThreadLocal.get().setTotalTimeTaken(loggingThreadLocal.get().getEndTime() - loggingThreadLocal.get().getStartTime());
        logIntegration(invokingServiceName, loggingThreadLocal.get().isSuccess(),
                loggingThreadLocal.get().getFailureReason(), loggingThreadLocal.get().getTotalTimeTaken());
        System.out.println("Inside before request");
    }

    public void serviceCallException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception ex){
        loggingThreadLocal.get().setSuccess(false);
        loggingThreadLocal.get().setFailureReason(FailureReason.GENERIC_REMOTE_ERROR);
        System.out.println("Calling method: "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Testing this obj: " + joinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Testing source: " + joinPoint.getSourceLocation().getClass().getName());
        String invokingServiceName = joinPoint.getClass().toString();
        logIntegration(invokingServiceName, loggingThreadLocal.get().isSuccess(), 
                loggingThreadLocal.get().getFailureReason(), loggingThreadLocal.get().getTotalTimeTaken());

    }
```

logIntegration method is used for logging the details, but the call to this file doesn't seem to be happening.

I have not made any change in the method SearchManager.getSearchData().
The arguments to be passed to getSearchData are:String city, String zipcode, String name, String[] filters

I believe I don't need to ad annotations, since I have defined everything in my application-context.xml

I cant seem to find any point I have missed.
Any pointers from here would be of great help.

Thanks.

Edit: After comments, I guess this information is also neededL
My Manager class makes the call to Services client. I have tried to use AOP proxy on my Manager Class.
For example:

```
ManagerClass{
ServicesClient servicesClientInstance;
SearchRequest request; //dummy search request object to be sent to service
public makeCallToServices{
    ServiceResponse response = (ServiceResponse)servicesClientInstance.getSearchResult(request);
}
}
```

Now my aop point-cut is defined in applicationcontext.xml like this:
.....

```
<aop:pointcut id="servicesCall"
            expression="execution(* com.test.manager.ManagerClass.makeCallToServices(..))"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="servicesCall" method="beforeRequest"/>
```

......
beforeRequest, AfterRequest are defined in a separate class as shown above.

Comment: Make sure you don't have 2 instances of the service. AOP will only be applied to beans in the same application context. If your service is, alos, loaded in another context that wil not have AOP applied.

Comment: I suppose your service implements an interface, and the methods are systematically called via this interface injected in another bean to use the AOP proxy ?

Comment: Actually, the service client is a jar that I imported in my project. Does that have any implications that AOP will not work in this.

Comment: @Akshay, you haven't answered to any of the previous questions that were asked or addressed.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Added edit to answer your comment.